# How to play downloaded videos in android + iPhone webview

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net, web-applications

I am developing a web app for android + iphone in which I want to impliment following function.

If user is connected to WiFi he can play videos direct from server or can download videos to their devices. Later when they are on mobile network, they can play downloaded files in that  web app.

Is it possible? How can I do this? My Web app is server app written in `ASP.NET`.

Comment: Is is a web app or native android app? You mean you are developing a HTML 5 web app? Am I right?

Comment: It is a Hybrid app. First will be developed in HTML5 then will be emmbed in Android Webview.

Answer (score 2):

Actually HTML 5 applications can cache. But there's a size limit. Web apps in iOS safari can cache upto ~5MB offline. In Android it's ~2MB as far as I know. But you actually can't determine it's wifi or 3g via HTML 5. So I think the way you are trying to do the job may not work.

You can use native iOS and Android application for this purpose. You may use some third party library / SDK which will export to Android and iOS (I don't know exact names). But writing native app is the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: My videos are in GBs. Means cache will not work for me. And I don't want to go for native because I have little experice in Android and no experince in iOS. Thanks for replying.. :)